# Can I use an array in PHP as associative and also numbed ?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associative array like this

```
$imagePaths = array(
    'logo'          => "logo.jpg",
    'facebook-logo' => "facebook-icon.jpg",
    'twitter-logo'  => "twitter-icon.jpg",
    'linkedin'      => "linkedIn.jpg"
);
```

for me to call logo, I use below code

```
$ClassInstance->imagePaths['logo'];
```

But I would also like to be able to call it using

```
$ClassInstance->imagePaths[0];
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could store a second array using [`array_values()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php):

`$imagePathsKeyed = array_values($imagePaths);`

***EDIT:** I've expanded the example code to help here*

```
<?php
class SomeObject
{
    public $imagePaths;
    public $keyedImagePaths;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->imagePaths = array(
            'logo'          => "logo.jpg",
            'facebook-logo' => "facebook-icon.jpg",
            'twitter-logo'  => "twitter-icon.jpg",
            'linkedin'      => "linkedIn.jpg"
        );

        $this->keyedImagePaths = array_values($this->imagePaths);
    }
}

$classInstance = new SomeObject();
// logo.jpg
echo $classInstance->imagePaths['logo'];
// logo.jpg
echo $classInstance->keyedImagePaths[0];
```

Comment: Ok thank you. Looking at both answers, Can anyone give any more info on which option would be the better, in terms of performance/bugs? This answer seems easier to me as I just call a separate array for numbered Array, whereas as the previous answer requires me to call 2 arrays, one inside the other. Yet the previous answer has more up votes...

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this with [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/array_keys):

```
$keys = array_keys($imagePaths);
$ClassInstance->imagePaths[$keys[0]];
```